# ScrollView with scrollViews - what is the right way to do it?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Client wants some tricky stuff and i don't really know where to start with it.
The idea is that there is a horizontal scrollView whose each page consists of a vertical scrollView.
For example, on the horizontal axis there are galleries, on the vertical we scroll through selected gallery's images. Is this even possible?

I'd be very glad to hear comments on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manage the state yourself. When one scrollbar is selected the other has to be disabled and vice versa. You can also disable the user scrolling and handle the swiping yourself with the touch events. (on a clearColor UIView as a topmost view).

Answer (score -1):

They all works magically, there's no additional work for this unless there's an issue about memory consumption which will require more coding.

Simply, create a horizontal scroll view then add vertical scroll views into it. Don't forget to update the `contentSize` property.